# How to load a menu module in header and footer in joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, joomla-template, joomla-module

I have attached joomla's Menu module in my template. But I needed it to load in footer position at the same time. So that if I add another menu it should be get added in both the positions in Header and in the footer... What i want to do to load a menu module to two different positions in a page, in header and in footer.

I had tried to add multiple positions in administrator section for a menu module...

screen shots are as follows

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For latest version. Joomla3.x :
Get all the modules by template position(replace position with your template position):

```
<?php
$modules  = JModuleHelper::getModules("position");
$document = JFactory::getDocument();     
$attribs  = array();
$attribs['style'] = 'xhtml';
foreach ($modules as $mod) {
  echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($mod, $attribs);
}
?>
```

Other Solution: you can define position in the template and assign module to that position

Steps:
1.Customize templateDetails.xml file
add
newposition

2.create position in index file of template
in templates/your_template/index.php

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="newposition"   />
```

Comment: This will work for only 1 position..but i am having two different positions where i have to load same module in a page.

Comment: i found the way already but i wanted to know if this could work

Comment: Login at joomla administrator and follow the steps mentioned below:-

-Click on Modules under "Extensions" menu item
-select menu module and click on duplicate.
- publish and assign different position to the new duplicate module

Comment: If i change menu module i wont have to make changes in both right?

Comment: you mean Menu, Yes if make changes in menu assigned at two different positions, you don't have to make changes in both the menu modules.

Comment: Thank u very much mayank. it was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you should simply be able to duplicate your menu module (in extensions->modules) and add the duplicate module to a module position in the footer of your template. If there is no module position in the footer, you add one to the  - list in templateDetails.xml, and add it to index.php in your template, like:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer-menu" style="xhtml" />
```

Comment: can't i use same module to load in two different positions

Comment: You don't use the same module, you make a duplicate. If this don't work, I don't know why.

Comment: i understood what u want to say

Comment: You should try to better explain your question in your post. It is quite difficult to understand what is your actual problem.

Comment: Dont add it here, expand your post. Other people reading your post dont neccessarily read the comments on other answers. Also, what you are saying dont make sense. If you want to show the menu on more than one place, you will have to clone the markup somehow. The easiest way is to duplicate the module. You need to explain why you cannot use the normal approach. Good luck.

Comment: ohk i will write it inside question

Comment: That is good to hear. Feel free to upvote the answer (as you already marked the other one the correct answer) :)

Comment: Actually it needs 15 reputation at least to upvote...and u know someone downvote my question